# Debug.WriteLine() versus Console.WriteLine() handles culture differently. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, culture, date-formatting

Consider the following Console App code:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

DateTime date = new DateTime(2014, 01, 19);

Console.WriteLine("{0}", date); // Prints 19/01/2014
Debug.WriteLine("{0}", date);   // Prints 01/19/2014
Debug.WriteLine(date);          // Prints 19/01/2014
```

As noted in the comments, the `Console.WriteLine()` prints `19/01/2014` while the `Debug.WriteLine()` prints `01/19/2014`.

Even worse - `Debug.WriteLine("{0}", date)` gives different output from `Debug.WriteLine(date)`...

Is it expected that `Debug.WriteLine()` ignores the thread's culture settings?

Is there a way to make `Debug.WriteLine()` use the thread's culture settings? Or must I use `String.Format()` and pass the result to `Debug.WriteLine()`?

(Note: I'm running this on Windows 8.1 64-bit, en-GB, using Visual Studio 2013 with .Net 4.51 with a debug AnyCPU build.)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: That has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - that's for changing the destination, the damage (formatting) has already been done then.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is explicitly handled [in the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/diagnostics/Debug.cs,240).

It makes sense, too.
Debug output should not be affected by the end-users culture; you want your debug logs to be consistent no matter where the code is running.

Comment: Well, I've marked this as the answer, but I don't agree with the reasoning. Firstly, debug output will never occur on an end-user's computer (because it would be a release build, not a debug build). Secondly, I want to have the dates in UK format so I don't mix them up. Thirdly, it's common to use `string.Format()` to format messages for `Debug.WriteLine()`, so by mixing this you can get different outputs depending on whether you used `string.Format()` to construct an interim string.

Comment: And even worse, `Debug.WriteLine(date)` gives you a different result from `Debug.WriteLine("{0}", date)`!

Comment: @MatthewWatson Debug output will (hopefully) never occur on an end user's PC ... but it could easily come from multiple developer PC's where the developers are in several different countries.  In that scenario, I would want all the machines to be using the same culture settings.

Comment: This explains why Debug and Console are different, but not why `Debug.WriteLine("{0}", date);` is different from `Debug.WriteLine(date);`. Could you add a sentence about that?

Comment: @Ixrec: That's actually handled by the listeners.  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/diagnostics/TraceInternal.cs,482  They probably call `ToString()` directly.

Comment: @David And equally you could easily use `Debug.WriteLine(object)` in one case and `Debug.WriteLine(format, args)` in another - with different results. Clearly there is inconsistency here. Should the advice be to NEVER use `Debug.WriteLine(object)`?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I think the point is that whether you use `Debug.WriteLine(object)` or `Debug.WriteLine(format, args)`, in either / each case the output would be consistent regardless of culture.  As to the two overloads generating different output ... an argument could be made that debug / trace code should use one or the other, consistently. I'm not saying *I* would make that argument -- I tend to agree with you that this is bad UX -- but I'm pretty sure some of my present & former co-workers would do.

Answer (score 10):

The overload you are using [explicitly ignores the culture](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/diagnostics/Debug.cs,de18340cbf015ef1) by using `InvariantCulture`:

```
public static void WriteLine(string format, params object[] args) 
{
    TraceInternal.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, format, args));
}
```

All the other overloads don't do anything related to culture. You can "workaround" this by using the overload which takes a `string`:

```
public static void WriteLine(string message, string category)
{
    TraceInternal.WriteLine(message, category);
}
```

By doing this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

DateTime date = new DateTime(2014, 01, 19);

var formatedDate = string.Format("{0}", date);
Console.WriteLine(formatedDate);
Debug.WriteLine(formatedDate);
```

Now both print:

```
19/01/2014 00:00:00 
19/01/2014 00:00:00
```